# How to return custom message in web API Post method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, push-notification

I would like the following Post method to return a failure by assigning a failure value to the "`result`" variable but I am not sure how to achieve that. Ideally it would say that the installation id is invalid, but not sure I could do that:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost, Route("sendForDevelopment")]
public async Task<NotificationOutcome> Post([FromBody]string message, string installationId)
{

    string hubName = "myHubName";
    string hubNameDefaultShared = "myHubNameDefaultShared";

    NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient
                    .CreateClientFromConnectionString(hubNameDefaultShared, hubName, enableTestSend: true);

    var templateParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["messageParam"] = message
    };

    NotificationOutcome result = null;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(installationId))
    {
        // output a installation id is null or empty message or assign failure to the result variable
    }
    else
    {
        result = await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(templateParams, "$InstallationId:{" + installationId + "}").ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: have the result of the action be a `IHttpActionResult` derived object. That should allow greater flexibility as to what you can return

Comment: @Nkosi I was thinking something among those lines. if the result of the action is IHttpActionResult, it would also include same message in case of success as NotificationOutcomeResult or maybe similar?

Comment: Well then just create an instance of `NotificationOutcome` and populate as needed

Comment: @Nkosi i wasnt able to populate, i checkout the class definiton for NotificationOutcome but didnt figure out how to assign it a failure manually.

Comment: @Nkosi also I just tried IHttpActionResult but I get an error in the line result = await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(..) saying that it cannot implicitly convert NotificationOutcome to IHttpActionResult

Comment: No. you would need to wrap that in an `Ok(...)`

Comment: @Nkosi could you be more specific please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have the result of the action be a `IHttpActionResult` derived object.

That should allow greater flexibility as to what you can return when the request is not valid

For example

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost, Route("sendForDevelopment")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]string message, string installationId) {

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(installationId)) {
        var model = new {
            error = new {
                code = 400,
                message = "installation id is null or empty"
            }
        }
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.Badrequest, model); //400 Bad Request with error message
    }

    string hubName = "myHubName";
    string hubNameDefaultShared = "myHubNameDefaultShared";

    var hub = NotificationHubClient
                    .CreateClientFromConnectionString(hubNameDefaultShared, hubName, enableTestSend: true);

    var templateParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["messageParam"] = message
    };

    NotificationOutcome result = await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(templateParams, "$InstallationId:{" + installationId + "}").ConfigureAwait(false);
    return Ok(result); //200 OK with model result
}
```

For a bad request the response body would look something like

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "installation id is null or empty"
  }
}
```

On the client side you check the status code of the response and proceed accordingly.

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<NotificationOutcomeResult>();

    //...
else {
    //...check why request failed.
    var model = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ErrorResponse>();

    var message = model.error.message;

    //...
}

//...
```

Comment: @EmilRR1 I made some updates to the original answer.

Comment: Worked perfectly.